# Automate the "Add to Home Page" feature for an iPhone Web App

Tags: iphone, web-applications

An iPhone WebApp can be added to the start buttons on the home pages of an iPhone.  This is done by pressing "Add to Home Page" within a browser page.  I would like to have something that would prompt the user to let them do this via JavaScript.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, this way:

alert("Voor betere weergave: \n 1. Klik op de '+' button onderin \n 2. Selecteer 'Zet in begrinscherm'  \n 3. Klik het iccontje aan op je homescreen");

It is in dutch because I am Dutch =D